# Bounding a continuous function away from another by affine transformation and scaling

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $g \in C([0,1]^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\epsilon >0$ be given.  Which non-constant functions $f \in C([0,1]^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfy
$$
\sup_{r>0,A\in Mat_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R}), b \in \mathbb{R}^d}\sup_{x \in [0,1]^d} \|r\cdot f (Ax+b) - g(x)\|_d \geq \epsilon?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ does not satisfy the inequality. This means that for all $A$, $b$, $r$, and $x$ as above, one has $|r f(Ax+b)-g(x)|\leq \epsilon$. The left side is a continuous function of $r$ when $A,b,x$ are fixed, and taking the limit as $r\to 0$ from above, one obtains that $|g(x)|\leq \epsilon$. Let $M=\sup_{x\in[0,1]^d} |f(Ax+b)|$. By compactness of $[0,1]^d$ and continuity of $|f(Ax+b)|$, it follows that $M=|f(Ay+b)|$ for some $y\in[0,1]^d$.

Suppose for contradiction that $M>0$. Then for all $r>2\epsilon/M$ one has that $|rf(Ay+b)|>2\epsilon$, meaning that at least one of the inequalities $|g(y)|\leq \epsilon$ and $|rf(Ay+b)-g(y)|\leq \epsilon$ must fail, a contradiction.

Hence $M=0$, meaning that $f$ vanishes on $A[0,1]^d+b$ for all $A$ and $b$. Tiling $\mathbb R^d$ with suitable translates of $[0,1]^d$, it follows that $f$ vanishes on all of $\mathbb R^d$.

Thus, we have shown that all non-constant (or even, non-identically zero) functions satisfy the inequality.